# Odoo app in v12 but I receive an error if I use it in v13

Tags: java, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-12, odoo-13

I have an app in v12 for Odoo, but now I try to use this app with the v13 but I can't, if I do the login receive this error:

> faultCode no element found: line 1, column 0 faultString Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-ivanOdoo/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 60, in xmlrpc_1 response = self._xmlrpc(service) File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-ivanOdoo/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 48, in _xmlrpc params, method = loads(data) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1020, in loads p.close() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 448, in close parser.Parse(b"", True) # end of data xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0

But with an Odoo in v12 it works, what can I do for use the app with my Odoo v13?

Comment: Could you please add the code of your app? Or give a link to a github repo, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the log that Odoo tries to parse empty content which ends with an `ExpatError: no element found`.

You need to migrate your code to Odoo-13, try to follow the OCA [tasks to do in the migration](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-13.0#tasks-to-do-in-the-migration).